# Can I add Java portlet in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, portlet

Can I add Java portlet in sharepoint 2007? If yes, can some please explain the details on how can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While its true you can't add a Java portlet directly to Sharepoint, Sharepoint is, at least in the feature list, a "W"eb "S"ervice "R"emote "P"ortlet client, or WSRP client. So what you would do is build your Java portlet, then deploy and run it on a portlet container that supports being a WSRP server, like Liferay...I think is one that'll do it. Once this is done, you should be able to import the remote portlet to Sharepoint. For Sharepoint 2007, here's a link that might help.

[MSDN Code page for Sharepoint 2007 WSRP tutorials](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WSRPToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1943)

Answer (score 3):

Not really, as [KB22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404726/can-i-add-java-portlet-in-sharepoint-2007/1404775#1404775) states. It doesn't support the portlet specification.

The answer partly depends on what the Java code needs to do. SharePoint has a Page Viewer Web Part that inserts an [`iframe`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp) into the page. If you host the portlet on a URL then the web part could point to it and include the rendered output within its iframe. This is probably the best option if you don't want to write SharePoint code.

Answer (score 1):

NetUnity provides a full featured SharePoint WSRP Consumer that supports WSRP 2.

http://www.netunitysoftware.com/SharePointConsumer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd doubt that this is possible  since sharepoint is .NET and java is obviously not.
Though vice versa this is not true, sharepoint portlets can be made compatible with java portals...